# Array.prototype.reduce in recursive function is producing unexpected results

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, recursion, ecmascript-5

I'm trying write a function to convert an Array to a DocumentFragment. Each item of the array will become an HTMLElement. It's tag name will be the array-item's class name*, and its attributes will be the properties of the array-item whose values are strings.

So for example, if I have these constructors:

```
function Person(name,pets){
        this.name=name;
        this.pets=pets;
    }
function Pet(name){this.name=name;}
```

And this data:

```
var arr=[
        new Person("Bob",[
            new Pet("Sparky"),
            new Pet("Wishbone")
        ]),
        new Person("Mary",[
            new Pet("Maggie"),
            new Pet("Sprinkles")
        ])
    ];
```

I use this function and it works great:

```
Array.prototype.toDocFrag=function(){
        return this.reduce(function(docFrag,currentItem){
            elem=document.createElement(currentItem.constructor.name.toLowerCase());
            for (prop in currentItem){
                if (typeof currentItem[prop]==="string") elem.setAttribute(prop,currentItem[prop])
                //if (currentItem[prop] instanceof Array) elem.appendChild(currentItem[prop].toDocFrag())
            }
            docFrag.appendChild(elem)
            return docFrag;
        },document.createDocumentFragment())
    }
```

If I run `arr.toDocFrag()`, I get a docFrag with the contents `<person name="Bob"></person><person name="Mary"></person>` as expected.

But now what I want to do is make it recursive, so that it sees "pets" and appends another DocumentFragment to each `<person>` so I end up with

```
<person name="Bob">
    <pet name="Sparky"></pet>
    <pet name="Wishbone"></pet>
</person>
<person name="Mary">
    <pet name="Maggie"></pet>
    <pet name="Sprinkles"></pet>
</person>
```

Uncomment out the line I commented out in my code, and I believe that it should work. But for some reason `arr.toDocFrag()` is returning just `<pet name="Wishbone"></pet><pet name="Sprinkles"></pet>`

What is wrong with my logic? Am I misunderstanding something about `Array.prototype.reduce` or recursive functions?

Thanks!

---

**Footnote**

*By class name I mean the name of the constructor that initiates the instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that `elem` is an [implicitly global variable](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). This doesn't matter for your first function, but completely messes up the recursive function where a call overwrites `elem` of his caller.

Use a [`var` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) to declare your variables locally (it's missing for `prop` as well). And use [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) to get errors on such behaviour.